# cannot convert from 'out double?' to 'out double'

Tags: c#-3.0

I have the following section of code in an app that I am writing:

```
    ...
    String[] Columns = Regex.Split(CurrentLine, Delimeter);
    Nullable<Double> AltFrom;
    ...
    if (AltFrom == null)
    {
       Double.TryParse(Columns[LatIndex].Trim(), out AltFrom);
    }
    ...
```

The line in the if clause will not compile and shows the error: **cannot convert from 'out double?' to 'out double'**

if I don't make AltFrom a Nullable type and rather explicitly state it as a Double, everything is happy.

Surely this is valid code. Is this just a bug in c# or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can not implicitly convert a `double?` to a `double`. The reason is because what would be the value of the `double` if the `double?` represented the `null` value (i.e., `value.HasValue` is false)? That is, converting from a `double?` to a `double` results in a loss of information (it is a narrowing conversion). Implicit narrowing conversions are generally frowned upon in the framework.

But actually, the problem that you are seeing here is something different. When you have a method that accepts an `out` parameter of type `T`, you must pass in a variable of type `T`; there can not be any type variation in this case as there is with non-`ref` and non-`out` parameters.

To get around your problem, use the following:

```
if (AltFrom == null) {
   double value;
   Double.TryParse(Columns[LatIndex].Trim(), out value);
   AltFrom = value;
}
```

Comment: Your logic makes sense, but I think you have it the wrong way around. I'm not converting from double? to a double. I'm converting from a string to a double? which should result in an internal conversion of a double to a double? If the double? held a null (or any other value) it would be irrelevant since it would be overwritten since it is the out parameter.

Comment: No, I do not have it backwards. You have declared `AltFrom` as a `Nullable<Double>` and are passing it as an `out` paramter to `Double.TryParse`. However, `Double.TryParse` is expecting an `out double`. So you are passing an `out double?` where `Double.TryParse` is expecting an `out double`. As I mentioned, out parameters can not vary from their declared type. Period.

Answer (score 7):

No the out parameter really needs to be a `double`, not a `Nullable<double>`.

```
double? altFrom = null;
double temp = 0;
if (double.TryParse( Columns[LatIndex].Trim(), out temp))
{
    altFrom = temp;
}
```

Comment: Actually, since it's an out parameter, initializing it to 0 is pointless.

Comment: @Dave, agreed. "out" denotes the parameter MUST be assign within the method.

Comment: Good habits die hard, I guess.